# Running bash script partially

Tags: bash

I have bash script 1.sh:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
```

What is the better way to execute only several commands, so in result I would get output:

```
1
2
```

or only:

```
3
4
```

Comment: Comment out the commands you don't want to run.

Comment: How do you want to decide which commands are run? Command line flags?

Comment: By given numbers of strings in that file, which I don't want to be executed. Like ./1.sh 3 4

Comment: Like drop first or last strings of that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
if you have a script in which each line is just a simple command like the one you are showing 1.sh, then you can execute only the line you choose by using awk and xargs

For example if you want to select only the line where is the 1 and execute it:

```
awk '/1/ {print $0}' 1.sh | sh
```

Or if you want to run the 3 record you can use:

```
awk '{if(NR == 3) print $0}' 1.sh | sh
```

On the other end you if can modify 1.sh then I would use an input parameter to choose which lines to execute, like in the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash

torun=$1

if [ "$torun" -eq 1 ] 
    then
        echo "run command 1"
        echo "run command 1b"
fi

if [ "$torun" -eq 2 ] 
    then
        echo "run command 2"
        echo "run command 2b"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't do. You suggest to copy commands to another script, and I need to read them from my 1.sh scripts.

Comment: So you don't want to modify 1.sh? But read it and conditionally execute only some commands of the script?

Comment: Yes, 1.sh have to stay without changes.

Comment: awk select the line and put it in stdin, xargs execute them (http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). I tested it and works.

Comment: No, it print 'echo 1' instead of '1'.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Now it works but is not what i would like to do, I will be back with a better solution in a while.

Comment: can you copy 1.sh on the server?

Comment: Yes, 1.sh will be on other server. I need to connect to it with ssh and then run this command.

Comment: try this: awk '{if(NR == 1) print $0}' $(PWD)/echothis.sh | xargs ssh server name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95577/discussion-between-terence-hill-and-sht0p0r).